# make a div responsive and content inside it

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to make my sign up form responsive, I have tried adding

In outer div

```
width:100%;
```

and in inner div

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

but I do not think it is working.
**Update**
I am on wordpress , this is my website [link](http://wpgeeks.net/) and here is the screenshot of the problem area. [link](http://prntscr.com/7uufle)

Comment: Could you add the entire HTML & CSS code regarding your sign up form to your question or make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please create a code snippet with your current css and html code.

Comment: I am on wordpress , this is my website [link](http://wpgeeks.net/) and here is the screenshot of the problem area. [link](http://prntscr.com/7uufle)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here something to fixe :

```
.sign_up_center {
    width: 100%; // responsive, for smaller screen
}
#field_2_1 {
    // force height, if not, your button goes on your field
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#input_2_1{
    // full size mail field
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#gform_submit_button_2{
    // full size submit button
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
body {
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  
  background:grey;
}
form {
  width: 50%; 
  min-height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align:center;
}
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
    sign in
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="password"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you should try to isolate your code, post that in your question, so we can better help you, this is not a place where we do your work for you. see @Paulie_D